# Different, Varied FlatList Items in React Native Without Data

Tags: javascript, react-native, listview

A good ole `<FlatList/>` is rendered like this is React Native:

```
function ListItem() {
    return (<View></View>);
}

function MyList({renderData}) {
    return (
    <FlatList
      data={renderData}
      renderItem={
        ({item}) => {
          return (
            <ListItem 
              fieldOne={item.fieldOne} 
              fieldTwo={item.fieldTwo}
            />
            )
        }
      }
    />
    )
}
```

That works well when a FlatList contains only one type of item (In this case the ListItem). However, it doesn't allow for different Components to be used throughout the FlatList unless we do some `renderItem` shenanigans:

```
function ListItem() {
    return (<View></View>);
}
function ListItemTwo() {
    return (<View></View>);
}
function MyList({renderData}) {
    return (
    <FlatList
      data={renderData}
      renderItem={
        ({item}) => {
          if( item.listItemType == 0 ){
          return (
            <ListItem 
              fieldOne={item.fieldOne} 
              fieldTwo={item.fieldTwo}
            />
            )
          } else {
            return <ListItemTwo fieldOne={item.fieldOne} fieldTwo={item.fieldTwo} />
          }
        }
      }
    />
    )
}
```

That works, but it depends on an additional field in each data item: `item.listItemType`, and it also depends on having an additional data item stored in data for each additional item I wish to display.

I am seeking a solution that instead allows for a hardcoding of an additional component that does not depend on that additional item being present in the data, and does not depend on the data at all.

Basically, I wish to create an item at the end of the `<FlatList>` that does not have a corresponding element in the `FlatList` data, as it does not need to display data. Is this possible in React Native? How?

Comment: Why not just use ScrollView?

Comment: @ThakurKarthik `<ScrollView />` does not support rendering data items from an array. I need to render data items from an array and also include a non-data item after the data items.

Comment: <ScrollView> {array.map(item=><some jsx/>)} <EXTRA ITEMS> </ScrollView>

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! I should've known there's a way to do for-loop type rendering in react-native. @ThakurKarthik

Comment: There is tons of reason why not to use ScrollView. The main and biggest is described in the react native documentation for ScrollView